Answering the question: if a point appears in this position in photo A, in what position does it appear in photo B?
I've been trying to find an algorithmic way of answering the following question:
Given the coordinates of a point p (e.g. a ground control point, or GCP), and two pictures IMG1 and IMG2 taken by a drone (with its latitude, longitude, altitude, pitch, yaw, roll known by EXIF data), if I know that point p appears in a certain pixel position, say (px, py) in IMG1, does the point also appear in IMG2? and if so, in what pixel position does it appear in it?
This is conceptually what I believe should be done to answer this question:

convert both the coordinates of p, IMG1, and IMG2 to UTM
compute the ground footprint of IMG1 and IMG2 (e.g. in meters)
compute the real-world distance of p from the center of IMG1 (using the position px, py. For example, using the Haversine distance)
compute the bearing angle of p with respect to the center of IMG1 (using the position px, py.)
compute the distance between the center of IMG1 and that of IMG2. Compute the bearing angle of the center of IMG2 with respect to that of IMG1. This should allow to know where the two pictures are with respect to one another in real-world measurements
Assuming the two pictures have the same width and height, translate the point starting from px, py according to its bearing angle and distance.

This is the general procedure I have come to.
I'm looking for input as to whether there are any conceptual mistakes in the above procedure.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. There are so many things that can go wrong, there  isn't yet an answerable Question. We are a problem-solving site. Why not implement your concept and see it it works, then if it doesn't you'll have a focused question.
